# Need to call a static factory method in a generic method (Error CS0119)

Tags: c#, generics, factory

I need to call a **static factory method** from a generic method.
Some solution suggest using reflection. Is there no other way to do so? Why C# has this constraint?

Here is my minimal example:

```cs
using System;

public class MainClass
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        A a = Get<A>("apiA");
        B b = Get<B>("apiB");
    }
    
    public static T Get<T>(string url)
    {
        string json = "{}"; // answer received from api
        return T.Factory(json); // error CS0119: 'T' is a type parameter, which is not valid in the given context
    }
}

class A {
    // public field
    public static A Factory(string json)
    {
        // need to do more A-specific thing here
        return NotUnderMyControl.FromJson<A>(json);
    }
}

class B {
    // public fields
    public static B Factory(string json)
    {
        // need to do more B-specific thing here
        return NotUnderMyControl.FromJson<B>(json);
    }
}

static class NotUnderMyControl {
    public static T FromJson<T>(string json) where T : new()
    {
        return new T();
    }
}
```

Comment: This is in fact possible with C# 11 using static virtual methods: `interface IFactory<T> { abstract static T Factory(string json); }`; `public static T Get<T>(string url) where T : IFactory<T> { ... }` and then have `A` and `B` implement `IFactory<A>` and `IFactory<B>`, respectively. This should also show why what you've written can't be allowed as-is: how should the compiler know a `Factory` method is available on every `T` you can pass in? C# generics are not like C++ templates in this regard.

Comment: Thanks, but this is a full answer, not just a solution :D you are right, i was thinking to much of C++ templates... I will try your idea of using an Interface constraint!

Comment: well sadly I'm in C# 8, so i have to find an other workaround..

Comment: Prior to C# 11 the natural approach would be to use instance-based factories rather than static methods. For example, using `Get<T>(...) where T : IFactory<T>, new()`, and then `new T().Factory(...)`. If creating a new instance seems distasteful or you want complicated creation logic encapsulated in the class itself, then a bit of reflection is almost unavoidable. Dependency injection frameworks take care of such things under the hood (which is both a benefit and a drawback).

Comment: I don't understand why you wouldn't call `NotUnderMyControl.FromJson<T>(json)` directly. What does the factory abstraction buy you here? If you have the new() constraint on your `A` and `B` types, it seems like you can bypass the entire abstraction.

Comment: @David L see the comments `// need to do more A-specific thing here`. Furthermore, it would be better design, as i have the creation of the object under the control of the object and not outsourced in different other code locations. The empty constructor is necessary so the FromJson can construct the object and fill i up with values. Yes you could bypass the Factory, however it would be an empty object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to make the methods common in the interface and change static methods to instance methods.

```cs
public class MainClass
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        A a = Get<A>("apiA");
        B b = Get<B>("apiB");
    }

    static class FactoryCache<T> where T : IFactory<T>, new()
    {
        public static readonly T Instance = new T();
    }

    public static T Get<T>(string url) where T : IFactory<T>, new()
    {
        string json = "{}"; // answer received from api

        return FactoryCache<T>.Instance.Factory(json);
    }
}

public interface IFactory<T>
{
    T Factory(string json);
}

class A : IFactory<A>
{
    public A Factory(string json)
    {
        return NotUnderMyControl.FromJson<A>(json);
    }
}

class B : IFactory<B>
{
    public B Factory(string json)    {
        return NotUnderMyControl.FromJson<B>(json);
    }
}
```

Comment: Since I can not use [Static abstract Interfaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-11.0/static-abstracts-in-interfaces) i guess that would be the only workaround..